# Is it Possible to Put Specific Information Into an Interface?

Tags: java

So I have a question about interfaces after experimenting for a bit: Can specific information be put into one?

Here's my interface:

```
public interface Weapon{
   public int damage();
   public int range();
   public String name();
   public int rateOfFire();
   public String[] applicableOperators();
   public void getSpecs(); //this is the method in which I have a question
}
```

Next, I implement it into the given gun: the R4C.

```
public class R4C implements Weapon{
   @Override
   public int damage(){
      return 34;
   }

   @Override
   public int range(){
      return 20; //meters
   }

   @Override
   public String name(){
      return "R4-C";
   }
   @Override
   public int rateOfFire(){
      return 850; //rounds per minute
   }

   public String[] applicableOperators(){
      String[] appOps = new String[1];
      appOps[0] = "Ash";
      return appOps;
   }
   public void getSpecs(){
      System.out.printf("Name: %s\nDamage: %d\n Rate of Fire: %d\n"
     + "Range: %d\n", name(), damage(), rateOfFire(), range());

      System.out.println("\nApplicable Operators:");

      for(int arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < applicableOperators().length; arrayCount++){
          System.out.printf("%s\n", applicableOperators()[arrayCount]);
      }
   }
}
```

So I want to have the "getSpecs" method ALWAYS have the same output. No matter which gun is being put in, I always want this same format:

Name: (WeaponName)

Damage: (Damage)

Rate of Fire: (RoF)

Range: (Range)

Applicable Operators:

Ash

Is there a way to do this inside an interface? Or would I just have to make a seperate method meant for output somewhere else? I know this is probably a basic question, but because I understand so little of interfaces so far, any input could help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in java>=8 you can define default method in interface :

```
public interface Weapon{
   public int damage();
   public int range();
   public String name();
   public int rateOfFire();
   public String[] applicableOperators();
   default public void getSpecs() {
       //this is the method in which I have a question
       System.out.printf("Name: %s\nDamage: %d\n Rate of Fire: %d\n"
                 + "Range: %d\n", name(), damage(), rateOfFire(), range());
       for(int arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < applicableOperators().length; arrayCount++){
              System.out.printf("%s\n", applicableOperators()[arrayCount]);
          }
   }
}
```

> Java 8 introduces “Default Method” or (Defender methods) new feature,
>   which allows developer to add new methods to the interfaces without
>   breaking the existing implementation of these interfaces. It provides
>   flexibility to allow interface define implementation which will use as
>   default in the situation where a concrete class fails to provide an
>   implementation for that method.

[Dzone article](https://dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could user interface default methods. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

Comment: You could make your answer even better by including an example. Is quite ease to do, would make your answer complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to archive this kind of function I recommend `abstract class` instead of `interface`

```
public abstract class Weapon {

    protected int damage;
    protected int range;
    protected int rateOfFire;
    protected String name;

    abstract public int damage();

    abstract public int range();

    abstract public String name();

    abstract public int rateOfFire();

    abstract public String[] applicableOperators();

    abstract public void getSpecs(); //this is the method in which I have a question
}


public class R4C extends Weapon {

    @Override
    public int damage() {
        return damage;
    }

    public void setDamage(int damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    @Override
    public int range() {
        return range;
    }

    public void setRange(int range) {
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    public int rateOfFire() {
        return rateOfFire;
    }

    public void setRateOfFire(int rateOfFire) {
        this.rateOfFire = rateOfFire;
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String[] applicableOperators() {
        String[] appOps = new String[1];
        appOps[0] = "Ash";
        return appOps;
    }

    public void getSpecs() {
        System.out.printf("Name: %s\nDamage: %d\n Rate of Fire: %d\n"
            + "Range: %d\n", name(), damage(), rateOfFire(), range());

        System.out.println("\nApplicable Operators:");

        for (int arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < applicableOperators().length; arrayCount++) {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", applicableOperators()[arrayCount]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can change value at run time easily using `setXXX` methods

Comment: I think this is't requirement specified. Or you can Declare variable in super class if there is no other purpose of super class